# Issue with flask-sockets's concurrent connection served by GUnicorn

Tags: python, sockets, concurrency, websocket, gunicorn

Flask-sockets use gevent-websocket and gunicorn to serve websocket.

But when I runs a client script to connect to server with over 300 connection, more connections are refused by gunicorn.

I have tried to config gunicorn and or inheirts from gevent-web-socket-worker but both of the way made no sense.

Linux's fd and connection limit maybe the problem, but value of them is far bigger than my poor 300 connections.

Environment:

```
CentOS 6.5 with kernel-33.12.8-0.2.x86_64 
Python 2.6.6
Flask 0.10.1
gunicorn 18.0
ws4py 0.3.4
gevent-websocket 0.9.5
gevent 1.0.2
```

I use [my own project](https://github.com/winkidney/flask-sockets-tornado)(forked from flask-sockets) to serve web-sockets.
Websocket server run by

```
gunicorn -b :9000 -k flask_sockets.worker flask_ws:app --debug  --log-level info --worker-connections 2000 --workers 8
```

The "--worker" and "--worker-connections" option has no effects on the concurrent connections.

```
from threading import Thread
import threading
from time import sleep
from ws4py.client.threadedclient import WebSocketClient

HOST = "ws://127.0.0.1:9000/echo2"


class EchoClient(WebSocketClient):

    def __init__(self, url, client_id, *args):
        super(EchoClient, self).__init__(url, *args)
        self.id = client_id

    def opened(self):
        print("connetcion %s opend!" % self.id)

    def closed(self, code, reason):
        print(("Closed down", code, reason))

    def received_message(self, m):
        print("#%s" % m)
        if len(m) == 175:
            self.close(reason='bye bye')

def run(cid):
    client = EchoClient(HOST, cid)
    client.connect()
    client.send("hello1")
    client.send("hello2")
    while True:
        sleep(10)

def multi_run():
    threads = [Thread(target=run, args=(x, )) for x in range(300)]
    for thread in threads:
        thread.setDaemon(True)

    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    multi_run()
```

This is my client-side script, when i run this script , the first 280 client can connect to server and works well, the last 20 client got error like

```
connetcion 244 opend!
connetcion 242 opend!
connetcion 245 opend!
connetcion 247 opend!
Exception in thread Thread-249:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.py", line 484, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "client.py", line 32, in run
    client.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ws4py/client/__init__.py", line 237, in connect
    self.handshake_ok()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ws4py/client/threadedclient.py", line 68, in handshake_ok
    self._th.start()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.py", line 474, in start
    _start_new_thread(self.__bootstrap, ())
error: can't start new thread
```

At server-side, I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 508, in handle_one_response
    self.run_application()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/geventwebsocket/handler.py", line 76, in run_application
    self.run_websocket()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/geventwebsocket/handler.py", line 52, in run_websocket
    self.application(self.environ, lambda s, h, e=None: [])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/winkidney/workspace/flask_ws/flask-sockets/flask_sockets/__init__.py", line 40, in __call__
    handler(environment_ws)
  File "/home/winkidney/workspace/flask_ws/flask-sockets/flask_sockets/__init__.py", line 79, in get_instance
    return cls()(ws)
  File "/home/winkidney/workspace/flask_ws/flask-sockets/flask_sockets/contrib/__init__.py", line 30, in __call__
    self.protocol.on_message(message)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/geventwebsocket/protocols/base.py", line 11, in on_message
    self.app.on_message(message)
  File "/home/winkidney/workspace/flask_ws/flask-sockets/example/flask_ws.py", line 23, in on_message
    self.write_message("this is the client message from %s: %s" % (request.remote_addr, message))
  File "/home/winkidney/workspace/flask_ws/flask-sockets/flask_sockets/contrib/__init__.py", line 42, in write_message
    self.ws.send(message, binary)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/geventwebsocket/websocket.py", line 348, in send
    raise WebSocketError(MSG_SOCKET_DEAD)
WebSocketError: Socket is dead
{'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1',
 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'Upgrade',
 'HTTP_HOST': '127.0.0.1',
 'HTTP_ORIGIN': 'ws://127.0.0.1:9000/echo2',
 'HTTP_SEC_WEBSOCKET_KEY': 'fLip7N4OGt4hqbpK24EuBw==',
 'HTTP_SEC_WEBSOCKET_VERSION': '13',
 'HTTP_UPGRADE': 'websocket',
 'PATH_INFO': '/echo2',
 'QUERY_STRING': '',
 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1',
 'REMOTE_PORT': '28256',
 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
 'SCRIPT_NAME': '',
 'SERVER_NAME': 'localhost.localdomain',
 'SERVER_PORT': '9000',
 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1',
 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'gevent/1.0.2 gunicorn/18.0',
 'werkzeug.request': None,
 'wsgi.errors': <open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0x7fef077d81e0>,
 'wsgi.input': <gevent.pywsgi.Input object at 0x1ee9e10>,
 'wsgi.multiprocess': False,
 'wsgi.multithread': False,
 'wsgi.run_once': False,
 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
 'wsgi.version': (1, 0),
 'wsgi.websocket': None,
 'wsgi.websocket_version': '13'} failed with WebSocketError
```

Then I noticed that Gunicorn's documention said that

> worker_connections
>
> --worker-connections INT 1000
>
> The maximum number of simultaneous clients.
>
> This setting only affects the Eventlet and Gevent worker types.

I tried to inherits from GeventWebSocketWorker in flask_socket/**init**.py to replace the original Worker, but still not worked.

My code listed below:

```
from geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers import GeventWebSocketWorker

class Worker(GeventWebSocketWorker):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Worker).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.worker_connections = 10000
```

I'll appreciate it if you helps me to solve this problem or tell me the way to solve it: )

Answer (score 2):

In the end, the problem is here:

I change the fd for root user but runs the client as normal user.

I had to change ulimit for normal user following this link:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/162229/how-do-i-increase-the-open-files-limit-for-a-non-root-user

May this helps : )